# xpath for preceding sibling

Tags: python, xpath, lxml

I have the following html:

```
<div id="content-home">
  <p>some date 1</p>
  <div class="content"><p>bla1.1</p></div>
  <div class="content"><p>bla1.2</p></div>
  <p>some date 2</p>
  <div class="content"><p>bla2.1</p></div>
  <div class="content"><p>bla2.2</p></div>
  <div class="content"><p>bla2.3</p></div>
  <p>some date 3</p>
  <div class="content"><p>bla3.1</p></div>
  <div class="content"><p>bla3.2</p></div>
  <div class="content"><p>bla3.3</p></div>
  <div class="content"><p>bla3.4</p></div>
</div>
```

With xpath I want to get back the date for each div class content. With this:

```
tree.xpath("///div[@id='content-home']/p[following-sibling::div[@class='content']]/text()")
```

and also

```
tree.xpath("///div[@id='content-home']/p[preceding-sibling::div[@class='content']]/text()")
```

I get only a list with 3 entries. I want to get back 9 entries (2x date1, 3x date3 and 4x date4. I tried a lot of things but get keeping 3 entries (date1,date2,date3). How can i realise this. 
What i actually want to do is to register the date of each div content.

Can someone help please?

Comment: I do not see any @class='post' in the data.

Comment: Of course that shoud be @class="content". Just edited. But the result is the same.

Comment: You'd need XPath 2.0 for that which isn't supported by lxml.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I don't immediately see a single XPath expression that does this, but some intermediate Python makes it easy enough:

```
>>> divs = x.xpath("//div[@class='content'][preceding-sibling::p]")
>>> [d.xpath("string((preceding-sibling::p)[last()])")
...  for d in divs]
['some date 1', 'some date 1', 'some date 2', 'some date 2', 'some date 2', 'some date 3', 'some date 3', 'some date 3', 'some date 3']
```

The second XPath expression can be read inside out:

```
preceding-sibling::p
```

denotes the preceding siblings of the `div` under consideration which have tag `p`. Of these,

```
(preceding-sibling::p)[last()]
```

is the last one. You need the parentheses because `[]` binds more strongly than `::`.

This is then wrapped in a `string()` call (because [`text()` is a code smell](http://developer.marklogic.com/blog/text-is-a-code-smell)) to get the string value out.

Comment: It works! But i actually don't understand your second line :(

Comment: @Geveze: posted an explanation.